# Spring / @Transactional with AspectJ is totally ignored

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I use Spring-Data Neo4j 2.2.0-RELEASE. (my following issue would be applicable to any other kind of entity mapping, why not JPA)

In my project, I have a public method annotated with `@Transactional` Spring's annotation, since I want to update/save an entity inside it:

```
public class MeetingServices {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;

    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void setMeetingRepository(MeetingRepository meetingRepository) {
        this.meetingRepository = meetingRepository;
    }

    @Transactional("neo4jTransactionManager")
    public void save(Meeting meeting) {
        User creator = userRepository.getUserByEmail("test@test.com");
        creator.participateIn(meeting); // this line leads to a NotInTransactionException since it signals that no transaction context is associated.
        meeting.setCreator(creator);
    }
```

My application-context.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="target/neo4jgraph" />
    </bean>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

    <bean id="meetingServices" class="services.MeetingServices">
        <property name="userRepository"><ref bean="userRepository"/></property>
        <property name="meetingRepository"><ref bean="meetingRepository"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userServices" class="services.UserServices">
        <property name="userRepository"><ref bean="userRepository"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="neo4jTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager">
                <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userTransaction">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl">
                <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="neo4jTransactionManager" />

    <!-- auto-generated repositories for Neo4j storage -->
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="repositories"/> 

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

As we see in this configuration, aspectJ is used for transactions.

So, I tried to test another way of doing by changing my application-context.xml to use the `proxy` feature instead of `aspectJ` feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="target/neo4jgraph" />
    </bean>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

    <bean id="meetingServices" class="services.MeetingServices">
        <property name="userRepository"><ref bean="userRepository"/></property>
        <property name="meetingRepository"><ref bean="meetingRepository"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userServices" class="services.UserServices">
        <property name="userRepository"><ref bean="userRepository"/></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" />


    <neo4j:repositories base-package="repositories"/>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

This configuration works pretty well since `@Transactional` (whose `neo4jTransactionManager` parameter was of course removed) annotation is now taken in account for my service's method.

My question is, (no matter whether my project would work with simple `proxy` method):

What did I miss or misconfigure in my first Spring's configuration that makes aspectJ transaction features failed?

I'm currently improving my technical skills with Spring, and read few articles about "Load-time weaving" for aspectJ. Might this be linked to my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding   `<context:load-time-weaver/>` to enable load time weaving and add the spring-aspects.jar to the classpath.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring for more info

**Edit**

For generic java applications, ie not running in a web or application container, you need to enable the java instrumentatioin via a javaagent option:

```
java -javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument.jar your.Main
```

If you want to weaving your own aspects, you need to provide a META-INF/aop.xml file with aspect declarations. (Not requiered for spring only aspects, it's already provided on spring-aspect.jar).

Finally you can use compile time weaving instead, [using the maven aspectj plugin,](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) for example:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but I end up with this:            `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar`

Comment: Add the option for the Main launcher: java -javaagent:C:/projects/foo/lib/global/spring-instrument.jar foo.Main as in reference example

Comment: I've just followed your advice :) but that leads to this: Caused by: `java.lang.VerifyError: (class: services/MeetingServices$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$73b088b5, method: setMeetingRepository signature: (Lrepositories/MeetingRepository;)V) Inconsistent stack height 1 != 0`. Sounds like a known bug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027009/aspectj-verifyerror). I use Java 7 .. I've just tried the advice: adding `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`to VM options but error still occurs.

Comment: Try with maven and compile time weaving. I just post an example. drop the ltw tag and the javaagent option. they are not requiered when using compile time weaving.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that (maven method) as soon as I come back to my computer, I'll inform you :)

Comment: The plugin doesn't work in eclipse. Following guidance in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522540/maven-ajdt-project-in-eclipse ...AJDT m2e Configurator fails during installation.  ...uninstall m2eclipse..install AJDT m2e Configurator still fails...install aspectJ development tools (Juno)..install AJDT m2e Configurator with m2e...and finally working with this config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844603/how-to-create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-with-aspectj-support. What a PITA!  Now aspectJ is weaved at compile time, but still no transactions.