# Getting "could not initialize proxy - no Session" despite the fact I'm using a @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, lazy-initialization

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I'm getting a "could not initialize proxy - no Session" exception, despite the fact I'm wrapping the relevant method call in a @Transactional annotation.  Here's my method …

```
@Service("teacherImportService")
public class TeacherImportServiceImpl extends AbstractmyprojectService 
{
    …
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveUserObject(final JsonObject jsonData)  
    {
        …
        final myprojectOrganization myprojectOrg = myprojectOrgDao.findBymyprojectOrgId(myprojectSchoolId);
        final Organization school = myprojectOrg != null ? myprojectOrg.getOrg() : null;
            …
        final Address address = new Address();
        address.setState(school.getState());    // error occurs here
```

What else do I have to do to guarantee a transaction takes place?  I have included the "<tx:annotation-driven />" in my application context, which I include below

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco" />
...
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${test.mysql.dataSource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${test.mysql.dataSource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${test.mysql.db.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${test.mysql.db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mainco.subco" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" /> 
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
</util:map>

<bean id="sharedEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:truncate_tables.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:db-test-data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Here is full stack trace of the exception ...

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization_$$_javassist_30.getState(Organization_$$_javassist_30.java)
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TeacherImportServiceImpl.saveUserObject(TeacherImportServiceImpl.java:101)
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers(AbstractmyprojectService.java:226)
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.AbstractmyprojectService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d080e416.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TeacherImportServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a06c7e9f.saveUsers(<generated>)
    at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.TeacherImportServiceTest.testSaveTeachers(TeacherImportServiceTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Do you have a `TransactionManager`?

Comment: Yes.  I edited to include the relevant portion from my application context in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some `@OneToOne` mapping on `Organization` for the state field. I suggest adding/changing the `FetchType` to `EAGER`. I can't see why it doesn't find a `Session` though.

Comment: a) Please add the source code of myprojectOrgDao. b) How is the test class annotated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add the transactional annotation to `AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers()`

Note that inner calls are never proxied, so the flow:

```
 TeacherImportServiceTest.testSaveTeachers() -> 
 AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers() -> 
 TeacherImportServiceImpl.saveUserObject()
```

Will not be transactional if `AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers()` is not transactional at all.

**EDIT**

After reading your comments, I see three options to solve it:

- **Extract the `saveUsers()` method to a helper class**.

Really simple, refactor your code to keep the Tx methods in one class and use it from another one via composition.

- **Use programmatic transactions in `saveUserObject()`**.

for example, inject the txManager and

```
public void saveUserObject() {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
        try {
          // the code
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          txManager.rollback(status);
          throw ex;
        }
        txManager.commit(status);
    }
```

- **Use AspectJ instead Spring AOP.** (I think that this option is too complex only for this issue.)

Using AspectJ you replace AOP Proxies wiht the Aspect `AnnotationTransactionAspect`

use `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>` and choose a weaving method (compile or load time).

for load time weaving, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

for compile time weaving with maven, see [Spring / @Transactional with AspectJ is totally ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616710/)

Comment: Indeed AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers is not transactional, but I  don't want saving of all users to either fail or succeed, I'd like the saving of each user to be an individual transaction.  Is there a series of annotations that can make that work?

Comment: No, Proxy based transaction demacarcation have limitations. You need to call saveUserObject() from a outer class, ie teacherImportService.saveUserObject(), not from this.saveUserObject(). You could move out the saveUsers() method (easy) or use AspectJ (more complex)

Comment: With aspectj, do I have to move my method to a separate class?  Do you have an example?  I really want to reuse functionality in the abstract class.

Comment: There is an ugly workaround - you neet to call through a proxy on a last call. `AbstractmyprojectService` would have to autowire i.e. `ListableBeanFactory` and than the last call would have to look like `BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType(beanFactory, getClass()).saveUserObject()`. But don't do that. Also I advice against `AspectJ` in this case - it'll get too complex too fast. Better [refactor to composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

In your application context XML, I don't see the component scan configuration which would let Spring to manage the stereo type annotated bean classes [i.e., Classes annotated with either **@Service**, **@Repository** or **@Component**]

Just add the package scan for any of such classes as in below example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.where.stereotypedclassesexist"/>
```

Regarding classpath scanning for spring managed components, Spring Documentation Reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html).

HTH.

Comment: I did have that but it wasn't reflected in my answer, which is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the [proxy implementation pattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies). Try extracting `saveUserObject` to an interface:

```
public class TeacherImportServiceImpl extends AbstractmyprojectService implements SomeInterface {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveUserObject(final JsonObject jsonData)  {
        ...
    }

}

public interface SomeInterface {
   void saveUserObject(JsonObject jsonData);
}
```

You may also try class-based proxing using CGLIB:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you asked:

> Indeed AbstractmyprojectService.saveUsers is not transactional, but I don't want saving of all users to either fail or succeed, I'd like the saving of each user to be an individual transaction. Is there a series of annotations that can make that work?

You could try setting a propagation type:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

That way, each user will be saved in his/her/its/... own transactions. Mind the performance, though. See also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation .