# Spring pointcut for abstract class' protected method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using `Spring 3.2` and `AspectJ 1.7.1`. (It is not likely that I can upgrade to later versions in the near future.)

I need to define a pointcut for a protected method in an abstract class. AFAIK I need `AspectJ` for methods that are not public, so I have only tried this with the (`AspectJ`) annotations:

```
package com.aspects;
@Aspect
public class Aspect{

    @Before("execution(* com.x.y.x.MyClass.myMethod(..))")
    public void beforeAspect(){
       //do something here
    }

}
```

In my `beans.xml` I have:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.aspects.Aspect"/>
```

I have checked and my `Aspect` class is created (constructor is getting called), no exception is being thrown when the application is launched.
However I can not get the `beforeAspect` to be called. For public methods in non abstract classes this works. How can I make it work for protected method in abstract class?

Answer (score 10):

You should add a `+` sign after the abstract class.

So

```
"execution(* com.x.y.x.MyClass.myMethod(..))"
```

should look like:

```
"execution(* com.x.y.x.MyClass+.myMethod(..))"
                              ↑
```

The `+` is about inheritance either extending the given class (`MyClass`) or implementing an interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it and will (hopefully) come back with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your are using @AspectJ-style to configure Spring AOP. the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` declares an `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator`  `BeanPostProcessor` but you need to run the aspectj compiler instead.

See [9.8 Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) in reference documentantion for more info about weaving aspects with Spring.

See [Spring / @Transactional with AspectJ is totally ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616710/spring-transactional-with-aspectj-is-totally-ignored) for more info about configure compile time weaving with maven.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I am reading the documentation. I did not know I am not using the `AspectJ` compiler.